# Función para ventilador mecánico

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, sensor

estoy programando una aplicación de un respirador mecánico, en python, raspberry Pi 4 y arduino uno, con un ventilador para uso médico (con mascarilla para respirar) que muestra el flujo en una gráfica por medio de mathplotlib y un sensor Sensirion smf3000 , hasta ahora puedo medir el flujo por medio del sensor, modificar la velocidad del ventilador gracias a un Slidebar y mostrar los datos cuando el paciente inspira y aspira en una gráfica en tiempo real.

El problema que encuentro es programar una función en donde una vez que he definido la velocidad del ventilador detecte cuando el paciente inspira e inmediatamente suba su velocidad para ayudar a respirar al paciente y también que cuando detecte que la persona esta exhalando baje su velocidad, espero puedan ayudarme.

Ejemplo: con el slidebar seteo la velocidad del ventilador en 50, el paciente inhala y el ventilador debe subir su velocidad a 80 concluye de inhalar y empieza a exhalar, el ventilador debe de reducir su velocidad a 15 y asi sucesivamente.

Les comparto el código en python:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import serial as ser
import time
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import argparse
import sys
import requests
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

global condicion, data
flujo=0
ciclo=0

data = np.array([])
condicion = False

#creamos la ventana principal
raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Respirador")
raiz.geometry("850x420")
raiz.config(bg="gray")

#agregamos los frames

frame1 = Frame(raiz)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.config(bg="gray")
frame1.config(width="520", height="335")

contenedor = Frame(raiz)
contenedor.grid(row=0, column=1)
contenedor.config(bg="red")
contenedor.config(width="220", height="400")


fValores = Frame(contenedor)
fValores.grid(row=0, column=0)
fValores.config(bg="gray", highlightbackground="black", highlightthicknes=1)
fValores.config(width="320", height="130")

lbTemperatura = Label(fValores, text= "TEMPERATURA:", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 12) ).place(x=70, y=15)
#lbvalorTemperatura = Label(fValores, text="", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=70 y= 40)

lbOxigeno = Label(fValores, text= "NIVEL DE OXIGENO:", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 12)).place(x=50, y=85)
#lbvalorOxigeno = Label(fValores, text="", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=135, y= 85)

ffoto = Frame(contenedor)
ffoto.grid(row=1, column=0)
ffoto.config(bg="gray", highlightbackground="black", highlightthicknes=1)
ffoto.config(width="320", height="130")

foto_paciente = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("perfil.png"))
 
lbFoto = Label(ffoto, image = foto_paciente).place(x=15, y=15)


lbNombre = Label(ffoto, text="Nombre: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=12)
lbEdad = Label(ffoto, text="Edad: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=37)
lbSexo = Label(ffoto, text="Sexo: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=62)
lbUnidad = Label(ffoto, text="Unidad: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=87)
lbfFolio = Label(ffoto, text="Folio: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=112)

# valores del paciente

lbNombre_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=195, y=12)
lbEdad_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=185, y=37)
lbSexo_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=185, y=62)
lbUnidad_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=195, y=87)
lbfFolio_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=185, y=112)

#control de escala

fControlador = Frame(contenedor)
fControlador.grid(row=2, column=0)
fControlador.config(bg="gray", highlightbackground="black", highlightthicknes=1)
fControlador.config(width="320", height="150")

lbControl = Label(fControlador, text="Nivel de Flujo: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 18)).place(x=30, y=3)

Slider_control = Scale(fControlador, from_=10, to=99, length=200,
                       resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                       command=getFlujo,
                       tickinterval = 20,
                       fg = 'white',
                       bg = 'black').place(x=40, y=55)

#creamos los botones

raiz.update();

btnIniciar = Button(raiz, text = "Iniciar", font = ('calibri', 12),
                  command = lambda: plot_Iniciar())

btnIniciar.place(x=150, y=350)


raiz.update();

btnDetener = Button(raiz, text = "Detener", font = ('calibri', 12),
                  command = lambda: plot_Detener())

btnDetener.place(x=btnIniciar.winfo_x()+btnIniciar.winfo_reqwidth() + 80, y = 350)


#eventos de la ventana

def cerrar_ventana():
    raiz.destroy()

raiz.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", cerrar_ventana)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(32,GPIO.OUT)

pin32 = GPIO.PWM(32,100)
pin32.start(0)


###iniciar la conexion serial
s = ser.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
s.reset_input_buffer()

#aqui se adquieren los datos de la conexion serial
def plot_data():
    global data

    if(condicion == True):

        a = s.readline()
        a.decode()
        flujo = a.decode()
        lbvalorTemperatura = Label(fValores, text= flujo + "    ", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=135, y= 40)


        if len(data) < 10:
            data = np.append(data, float(a[0:4]))
        else:
            data[0:9] = data[1:10]
            data[9] = float(a[0:4])
        lines.set_xdata(np.arange(0,len(data)))
        lines.set_ydata(data)
        
        canvas.draw()

    
    raiz.after(1, plot_data)


#creamos la grafica
style.use("dark_background")
fig = Figure();
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_title('FLUJO')
ax.set_xlabel("Tiempo")
ax.set_ylabel("Nivel de flujo")
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
lines = ax.plot([],[])[0]

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = frame1)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=5, y =0, width= 500, height = 280)
canvas.draw()

#detener la transmision de datos con el boton detener
def plot_Iniciar():
    global condicion
    condicion = True
    s.reset_input_buffer()

#iniciar la transmision de datos con el boton iniciar
def plot_Detener():
    global condicion
    condicion = False

#aqui se define el valor del slider para controlar la velocidad del ventilador   
def getFlujo(val):
    ciclo=20
    print(val)
    lbvalorOxigeno = Label(fValores, text=val, bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Digital", 15)).place(x=135, y= 110)
    ciclo= val
    pin32.ChangeDutyCycle(int(ciclo))


raiz.after(1, plot_data)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por aclarar un poco, ya tienes un proceso que dibuja el gráfico cada milisegundo. De igual modo, se podría ampliar para que consulte si el paciente inspira o expira para alterar la velocidad según esté parametrizado. El problema es que no veo claramente cuál es la señal que haría este cambio de velocidad. Te recomendaría separar mejor la parte del interface gráfico (tkinter) del control de la rasp/arduino (gpio) dando nombre significativos a las señales.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder Chema, he seguido tus recomendaciones y acomodé un poco el código y añadí comentarios un poco mas descriptivos, no he programado alguna función que detecte el cambio de velocidad, ese es el problema, he pensado en detectar la frecuencia respiratoria del paciente y en base a eso determinar la duración de un ciclo de respiración, es decir desde que inspira hasta que expira una sola vez, y entendiendo que la inspiración equivale a 1/3 del ciclo y la expiración 2/3, podré detectar el valor en el que el paciente empieza a inspirar y expirar pero aún no lo tengo claro

Comment: StackOverflow tiene una pagina sobre [Raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) y también hay un [foro](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/), Quizás te puedan ayudar

Answer (score 6):

No tengo conocimientos profundos de Python y sin tener el hardware con el que replicar lo que tienes no me atrevo a escribirte el código, pero te comparto algunos aspectos sobre el tema, aunque casi con toda seguridad más de uno ya lo hayas tenido en cuenta y estudiado antes de iniciar tu proyecto.

Teniendo en cuenta que se trata de un equipo de apoyo vital, la seguridad del funcionamiento tiene que ser clave y centro en todo el diseño.

Primero aisla completamente la implementación del funcionamiento y el control del ventilador de la implementación de la interfaz visual, incluso a nivel de procesos. Deben ser procesos independientes.

El parámetro de control principal que debes tener en cuenta es la presión del aire, luego su flujo. Si la presión que mides disminuye y se vuelve negativa (si se hace casi cero y se mantiene muy probablemente el paciente está desconectado) quiere decir que el paciente está inspirando y que el flujo de aire proveído por el ventilador podría no ser suficiente. Si es positiva, entonces tienes que aplicar mecanismos de control para limitarla.

Hay varios modos de funcionamiento de los ventiladores, los puedes buscar y estudiar, pero cuando es en modo "apoyo" y no "forzado" te interesa tener una presión positiva que a veces puede ser quasi- constante. La ventilación forzada es riesgosa, puede provocar roturas de capilares en los alveolos si no se controla correctamente, así que no me parece un buen punto de comienzo,

El ciclo de respiración, muy simplificado, es inspiración->pausa->espiración->pausa...etc... La pausa no es el suspiro, ni la inspiración profunda, que se produce uno cada alrededor de 100 ciclos, sino un momento en el que cambia la dirección del flujo de aire en la tráquea y por lo tanto hay un cambio de gradiente de presión. Para detectar los cambios de fase lo puedes hacer con el sensor de presión.

Si tienes los sensores y todo conectado y disponible, puedes poner el ventilador en una velocidad constante, conectarte la máscara, y capturar los datos durante 15~20 ciclos con respiración normal. El modo más simple de control que puedes utilizar es mediante un regulador [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller), hay unos cuantos proyectos de códigos abierto disponibles con los que puedes experimentar.

Yo te sugeriría, de serte posible, que crearas un proyecto OpenSource con los datos del hardware, esquemas, etc, que otros pudieran reproducir y colaborar, aunque ya hay varios proyectos similares y tal vez te interese colaborar en alguno.

Comment: Excelente, lo tomaré en cuenta, probaré con el regulador PID, realmente no había pensado en eso, muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 3):

Me falta mucha información de tu proyecto como para darte una respuesta más certera (si es que la tuviera). De todas formas te comento algunas ideas que creo te pueden ayudar.

Asumo que lo que necesitás es mantener la presión constante en todo el ciclo de respiración del paciente, modificando la velocidad del ventilador. Desconozco qué tipo de motor usa el ventilador, así que todo lo que te diga será genérico.

Para manejar el motor del ventilador usaría siempre un [PWM - Modulador por Ancho de Pulso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulaci%C3%B3n_por_ancho_de_pulsos#en_los_motores) (desconozco si así lo estás haciendo). La señal de realimentación del PWM sería la presion leída en el sensor, y la señal de control, la presión deseada en todo momento.

Para el PWM tenés en principio 3 alternativas:

1. Por software
2. Por hardware
3. Una combinación de las dos anteriores

Antes que nada acá tenés un [PWM con arduino uno](https://hetpro-store.com/TUTORIALES/arduino-pwm/)

Vamos de la última a la primera. Un ejemplo de un PWM combinado, lo constituye por ejemplo un microcontrolador con PWM incorporado, lo podés controlar con el soft en el mismo chip, pero la implementación está en el chip físico.

Por hard 100% tenés la ventaja de un circuito 100% dedicado y casi o totalmente independiente que no te consumiría ciclos de trabajo, salvo para monitoreo, incluso las alarmas y control de emergencia podés hacerlo por hard. Hay muchas formas, pero para probar, hasta podés armar un PWM con un circuito integrado 555. Otra forma es con un comparador con amplificador operacional. En ambos casos vas a necesitar la etapa de potencia para controlar el motor.

Por último, por soft 100%, te escribí un código de ejemplo muy muy genérico que haría lo mismo que el PWM:

```
import time

def obtener_presion():
    return presion

def activar_ventilador():
    pass

def desactivar_ventilador():
    pass

def control_ventilador(presion_deseada):
    if presion_deseada > obtener_presion():
        activar_ventilador()
    elif presion_deseada < obtener_presion():
        desactivar_ventilador()

encender = 'ON'
while (encender == 'ON'):
    control_ventilador(presion_deseada)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Las 3 primeras funciones las tenés que implementar vos (yo no tengo forma). Por último te hice en base al mismo código, uno de ejemplo que podés ejecutar para ver el funcionamiento del PWM de forma un poco más gráfica en la salida de un terminal. Podés cambiarle la presión objetivo y los incrementos/decrementos (si uno es par el otro debería ser impar para que no se estanque)

```
import time

class ventilador:

    presion = 0

    def obtener_presion(self):
        return self.presion


    def activar_ventilador(self):
        self.presion += 2


    def desactivar_ventilador(self):
        self.presion -= 2


    def control_ventilador(self, preset):
        if preset > self.obtener_presion():
            self.activar_ventilador()
        elif preset < self.obtener_presion():
            self.desactivar_ventilador()

instancia = ventilador()
for i in range(20):
    instancia.control_ventilador(13)
    print('Presión:', instancia.obtener_presion(),
          '-- ' + '*' * instancia.obtener_presion())
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

**Nota:** yo usé delays a modo de ejemplo, pero eso evidentemente es muy poco eficiente. Deberías usar (para llamar a la función de control) una interrupción (ya sea externa o generada por soft). Mejor aún, ambos sistemas.

Espero que te sirva y suerte con el proyecto. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Excelente bro, lo voy a poner en practica, muchísimas gracias!! saludos.